# Secure Donations Wallet for the RCK

Tags: wallet

Hi I am looking into a secure donations wallet for the RCK - Refugee Community Kitchen. http://refugeecommunitykitchen.com/
 Theyre doing great work to provide a humanitarian response to the humanitarian crisis in Northern france. The founders are happy for me to work on setting up a secure wallet for donations which will open them up to support from the cryptocommunity. I just want to make sure its as easy to manage as possible as although I am totally confident that donors will know exactly what to do, the donations link will be added to their main webpage and ideally needs to be as maintenance free as possible. 
I've been over on the SAFEnet forum and been given alot of good advice and pointed in the direction of Copay. 
I understand from help on the forum that because its open source and multi sig Copay is a great option.
What I cannot seem to grasp is if a Copay wallet is suitable for donations of other cryptocurrencies as well as Bitcoin? I know my questions are very basic - so is my understanding so I really appreciate your expert opinion. 
I looked at Coinomi as this seemed to readily support donations for lots of different coins. Am I missing something basic here? Can a Copay Wallet readily accept multiple types of cryptocurrency?
Thank you very much for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bitpay/copay

> Copay is a secure Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash wallet platform for both desktop and mobile devices.

Copay supports Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash only.  No other currencies are supported.